# text overflows in a div on Android mobile device only

Tags: android, html, css, text, overflow

this text overflows on my mobile device Samsung Galaxy S4. Seems to work on iphone. Can anyone help?
[www.printbubble.co.uk](http://www.printbubble.co.uk)
 has the div at the bottom and you will see that the text overflows at the bottom only on a mobile device of android.

CSS:

```
.productboxhalfdesc
{    
margin:0px 20px 0px 0px;
width:426px;
height:282px;
padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;
border:1px solid gray;
float: left;

}

.productboxwhole
{
margin:0px 20px 0px 0px;
width:898px;
height: 262px;
border:1px solid gray;
float: left;

}

.pbdesctable
{
margin: 0px;
vertical-align: top;
width:426px;
height:auto; 
border: 0px;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;

}
.pbdesc{
white-space: normal;
padding-top: 10px;
margin: 0px;
text-align: left;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 15px;
color: black;       
}
.pbdesc a:link 
{text-decoration:none;
text-align: left;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 15px;
color: #0099FF;    
}
.pbdesc a:visited 
{text-decoration:none;
text-align: left;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 15px;
color: #0099FF;    
}

.pbdesc a:hover
{text-decoration: underline;
text-align: left;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 15px;
color: #0099FF;    
}

.pbdesc a:active
{text-decoration:none;
text-align: left;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 15px;
color: #0099FF;    
}

.headingblue

{
padding-top: 15px;
margin: 0px;
text-align: left;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #0099FF;
}

.heading

{
padding-top: 10px;
margin: 0px;
text-align: left;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #0099FF;
}

.heading2

{
padding-top: 5px;
margin: 0px;
text-align: left;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #0099FF;
}
.headingblack

{
margin: 0px;
text-align: left;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
font-weight: bold;
color: black;
}
.heading a:hover
{
text-decoration: underline;
color: black;
}

.prodlink a:link 
{text-decoration:none;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
color: #0099FF;    
}
.prodlink a:visited 
{text-decoration:none;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
color: #0099FF;    
}
.prodlink a:hover
{text-decoration: underline;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
color: #0099FF;    
}

.prodlink a:active
{text-decoration:none;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
color: #0099FF;    
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="productboxhalfdesc">
<div class="pbdesctable">
<h1 class="headingblue">What else can Printbubble do?</h1>
<p class="pbdesc">Using the <a href="http://www.printbubble.co.uk/upload.asp">self-upload</a>, you can instantly request a quote against your own artwork. Using our variety of templates you can design yourself online, create your own leaflets, brochures and more. Personalise your iPhone covers or Samsung Galaxy covers, iPad cover. You can select a canvas from our library or upload your own image, a special occasion, holiday photo or anything you like! We can deliver personalised print worldwide, so Granny in Australia can have canvas print of a new arrival in the UK. <br /><i>Coming soon </i>&minus; we will be loading even more items so that you can create or select even more fantastic personalised printed items. </p>
<p class="pbdesc">Need any help? Contact us below:</p>
<h1 class="heading">E:&nbsp;<a href="http://www.printbubble.co.uk/upload.asp"><span class="headingblack">Contact Us Form</span></a></h1>
<h1 class="heading2">T:&nbsp;<span style="color: black;">020 8687 9234</span></h1>

</div>
</div>
```